# Get anchor href attribute using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button with the following javascript function:

```
function getHyperLink(){
  window.getSelection().anchorNode.parentNode.attributes["0"].nodeValue;
}
```

What i do is i highlight a text which contains a hyperlink, i then press the button and want go get the link from selected text.

The following above works but i want my code to be in jQuery if possible.

Comment: Your question not at all clear

Comment: Post your html code so that it will be easy to understand your question.

Comment: I highlight text from any webpage to get the links, if there were any text in the page that have hyperlinks embedded in them, i want to get those links too. So i use the getSelection() method first then i want get the hyperlinks from my selection

Comment: Use http://jsfiddle.net/ to create an example that we can interact with. Reading code is easier than reading a description of what it's doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) to get an attribute by its name:

```
var url = $(setContainingElement).attr('href');
```

Not sure how you're using it in your code, but you can use jQuery to wrap the native javascript object like so:

```
var url = $(window.getSelection().anchorNode.parentNode).attr('href');
```